# Low-pass filter capacitor configuration for differential output of an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, filter, low-pass

The diagram below shows the output stage of a bipolar diffential DAC amplifier powered from a dual supply (in my case I won't use an LM324 but an [OP484](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/op184_284_484.pdf)):

[image]

The amplifier outputs are fully differential (U1A and U1D are inverted.)

I want to make an RC low-pass filter for the output and I am not sure if I need C7. Which capacitors limit the output diffential noise and which CM noise? In practice, is it implemented like that, particularly for a diffential DAC amplifier output?

Comment: Are we done with this Q and A now user1245 or is further clarification needed?

Comment: I think I should empirically try it. But dont want to use chokes. Just capacitors. My input DAC signal is DC staircase ramp like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziDor.png where increment is 2mV and period of each DC stair is around 500us. The differential output will go to a driver of a galvo scanner- If you have a last input I will accept answer.

Comment: Maybe add that image and detail to your question as a clear edit so I can think about what you are saying with a clearer view.

Comment: Yes definitely thanks; but hopefully tomorrow Im very tired going to sleep soon.

Comment: Have you had any more thoughts about supplying the extra details?

Comment: The only detail I can say is the comment about application and BW I mentioned. CM chokes are for high freq inference isnt it? My application is not that high freq. also galvo scanner drivers have 12kHz or 6kHz already. The rest would be an entire question itself.

Comment: Which brings me back to my original comment @user1245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Which caps limits the output differential noise and which CM noise?*

With R9 and R10 as shown, C5 and C6 will attenuate (individually) both common mode and differential signals emanating from op-amps U1A and U1D. However, if C5 and C6 are not accurately matched they can actually convert CM signals into differential signals and this may cause problems.

Because of how C7 is placed it will only attenuate differential signals from U1A and U1D.

> *And in practice is it implanted like that?*

It works but, if you need better CM attenuation you would add a common-mode-choke in series with both op-amp outputs and possibly reduce R9 and R10. CM and differential chokes: -

[image]

Image from [A Guide to Understanding Common Mode Chokes](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/edu/series/a-guide-to-understanding-common-mode-chokes/).